# curl warning when passing a url

Tags: php, api, curl, instagram

I am debugging this issue for two days now but I couldn't found any issue of this code. Please guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'    => 1,
    'CURLOPT_URL'               => 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=' . $tocken,
    ));

$respond    = curl_exec($curl);

if(!$respond){
    echo curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

 curl_close($curl);

var_dump(json_decode($respond, true));
```

I am getting this error.

> Warning: curl_setopt_array() [function.curl-setopt-array]: Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /home/..../test.php on line 8
>   No URL set!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your array keys must be constants, not strings. Remove the quotes:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => 1,
CURLOPT_URL               => 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=' . $tocken,
));
```

Comment: Thanks... you rep over 100 now ok..:)

Comment: Don't do that: $curlOptions["CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS"] = $data;

Answer (score 2):

You should not quote the CURLOPT constant, because they are constant, not string. fix as fowllowing:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,  //notice, if your PHP > 5.1.3, no need to use this opt
    CURLOPT_URL            => 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=' . $tocken,
));
```